# CSS overwrite existing style for an element

Tags: html, css, hover

I am having a webpage with css style for an `<A>` tag. The style is also written for `A:Hover` for that tag. But i want to remove it for a particular tag alone. Can I set a property in CSS to have no change in value.

Lets us hope like this

```
A:hover {
font-family:no-change;
}
```

Or is there any particular way to avoid using the `A:tag` for that particular tag alone?

Comment: Define separate CSS classes for different types of tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your "particular" anchor tag has a class or id you could use `:not` pseudo class

```
a:not(.exemptedSelector):hover {  
 /*Your style goes here*/
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KSm7e/)

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot)

[Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot)

Or just provide a hover style for your "particular" anchor tag to override the style provided using `A` tag.

```
.exemptedSelector:hover
{
/*Your style goes here*/
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm generally not a fan of using !important where it doesn't need to be used.

In this case, you can use your general style for `<a>` tags

```
a:hover {
  font-family: 'Some weird font';
}
```

Then set a class or id or somesuch on the tag you want to behave differently, and use `inherit` to prevent the font from changing

```
a.special:hover {
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

This is the default value for the `font-family` property, and basically says "treat this element as if it didn't have its own style - just grab it from the parent like normal"

Answer (score 0):

Mention the font-name for that particular `a` and append `!important` to it. Like:

```
font-family:Arial !important;
```

Alternatively, create a class (say `.special`) with hover style and use that to the particular `a`:

```
.special:hover
{
    font-family:Arial;
}
```

I like the solution of PSL though.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `style` attribute and set the value of the `font-family` to override what the `css` says.

```
<a style="font-family: arial"></a>
```

[Example on jsFiddle using colors](http://jsfiddle.net/SSeqT/)

Answer (score 0):

give a class to your anchor, else this will affect all anchors:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="link_class">the link</a>
<a href="#" >other link</a>
<a href="#" >other link</a>
<a href="#" >other link</a>
```

CSS:

```
.link_class:hover{
 font-family: 'default_font_family' !important;
}
```

if you wish to apply to all anchors then:

CSS (do not use caps):

```
a:hover{
 font-family: 'default_font_family' !important;
}
```

Comment: typo -> important

Comment: Thanks @richardpringle, I fixed the typo.